# Smoothness of the closest point on a submanifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smoothness

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold, and let $S \subseteq M$ be a compact submanifold.

Assume that for each $p \in M$, there exist a **unique** closest point on $S$, i.e a unique point $\tilde s(p) \in S$ such that $d(p,\tilde s (p))=d_S(p)$.

It is easy to see the map $\tilde s:M \to S$ is continuous.

---

Is it differentiable? (at which points)?  If not, are there directional derivatives everywhere?

Does anything change if we assume every point has a **unique** minimizig geodesic to $S$? or that $M$ is complete? or both?

**Edit:** As shown in the example given by Willie Wong, when both conditions do not hold, $\tilde s$ does not have to be differentiable.

Answer (score 13):

Consider the following:

Take $M$ the plane with the standard (flat) metric, with the origin and the ray $[0,\infty) \times \{2\}$ removed.

Let $S$ be the unit circle centered at the origin. Clearly for every point in $M$ there exists a unique point on $S$ that is closest to it:

1. When $(x,y)\in M$ is such that either $x < 0$ or $y < 2$, then the closest point is $(x,y) / (x^2 + y^2)$.
2. On the other hand, when $(x,y)\in M$ is such that $x \geq 0$ and $y > 2$, then the closest point is $(0,1)\in S$.

Clearly this mapping from $M \to S$ given by the proximal point is not differentiable on the subset $\{(0,y): y > 2\}$.

Note however that this manifold does not satisfy the stronger version of the question where there "exists a minimizing geodesic", since the exponential map from $S$ is not surjective.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice example. I am wondering what is the situation if we restrict $(M,g)$ to be complete. (Of course, this does not imply that every point has a unique minimizig geodesic to $S$).

Comment: @AsafShachar: it is a lot more delicate! Try, for example, to run an abstract argument to prove that your map is differentiable on $M = \mathbb{T}^2$ and $S = \mathbb{T}$. There are some obstructions to running the inverse function theorem argument. One way I see requires identifying the conjugate points, showing it is a manifold, and using it to run some sort of implicit function theorem argument. And we also have to worry now about focal points since the [argument](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/242002/smoothness-of-the-closest-point-on-a-submanifold/242030#comment597507_242044) breaks.

Comment: @WillieWong Since the closest function is continuous but not generally differentiable as shown by your example, is it at least uniformly or better, Lipschitz continuous: By the way, I also wonder if the function $\tilde{s}:M\to S$ Lipchitz, i.e. can we say can we say $d_S(\tilde{s}(p), \tilde{s}(p'))\le Kd_M(p,p') \forall p, p'\in M?$? The submanifold $S$ may or may not be compact.

Comment: Cannot be Lipschitz. Just take $M = \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$ and $S$ the unit circle. Then $\tilde{s}(\epsilon,0) = (1,0)$ and $\tilde{s}(-\epsilon,0) = (-1,0)$. @Learningmath

Answer (score 5):

REVISED VERSION: My original answer was at best a mess. Here is what I think is a much shorter and cleaner version:

Assume that $M$ is an open Riemannian manifold and $S\subset M$ a submanifold such that there is a unique minimal geodesic joining each $x \in M$ to $\tilde{s}(x) \in S$. Since any minimizing geodesic must be normal to $S$, there is an open subset $\Omega$ of the normal bundle of $S$ such that the exponential map $\exp: \Omega \rightarrow M$ is a smooth bijective map. The argument given by Willie below shows that there are no focal points with respect to $S$ in $M$. This implies that the exponential map is a diffeomorphism. If $\pi: N_*S \rightarrow S$ is the bundle projection, then $\tilde{s} = \pi\circ\exp^{-1}$, which is a smooth submersion.

Comment: To highlight the key step in this outline: for (directional) differentiability to hold you need that "Given $v\in T_xM$, there exists a *unique* Jacobi field along the minimizing geodesic with $J(0) = v$." This is equivalent to the statement that "$x$ is not a focal point of $S$". This uses a bit more than the existence of unique minimal geodesic at $x$. (In fact, I haven't been able to clearly write out the argument giving "$\forall x \in M$ there exists unique minimizing geodesic from $x$ to $S$ $\implies$ $\forall x \in M$, $x$ is not a focal point." It sounds plausib, but I am not 100%.)

Comment: Willie, thanks for improving the answer. You're welcome to add more, if you think of anything else. As for it not being a focal point, it is because you can extend the geodesic a little bit (since $M$ is open) and it remains the unique minimizing geodesic.

Comment: As an aside, this answer is really about the exponential map from $S$ to $M$ and its differential. I always found discussions about the differential of the exponential map to be very confusing. I prefer to recast everything in terms of Jacobi fields. Although there is no use of curvature here, the application of Sturm-Liouville theory to Jacobi equation (essentially $J'' + KJ = 0$) is, I think, the easiest way to understand the role of curvature on the behavior of geodesics and the volume of geodesic balls and tubular neighborhoods of a submanifold.

Comment: @DeaneYang Thanks. Would you mind elaborating on the following points which I do not understand? (*Please see my answer below for details*)  1) Isn't $J(1)$ tangent to $S$, hence automatically orthogonal to the geodesic? (no need for projection) 2) I do not see why $J$ depends only on $v$, and furthermore, why is the dependence linear? 3) Finally, why this implies total differentiability? (not true in general). Thanks.

Comment: 1) You are correct. Otherwise, there is a length-decreasing variation that fixes $x$. 2) and 3): I think (everything I say should be viewed skeptically)  the key trick is to note that the exponential map is a smooth map from an open subset of the normal bundle of $S$ onto $M$. The Jacobi field argument above, or something like it, shows that the map is a diffeomorphism. Then $\tilde{s}$ is the composition of the inverse diffeomorphism with the bundle projection onto $S$.

Comment: It's known that a geodesic cannot be minimizing past a conjugate point (where some nontrivial Jacobi field vanishes). I glanced at a proof, and it appears to require the second variation of the length function. I believe the argument should extend to saying that a minimizing geodesic from a submanifold cannot go beyond the focal point. This would, I believe, complete the full argument.

Comment: To prove that the exponential map is a diffeomorphism requires there to be no focal point in $M$. This is equivalent to saying that if a set of Jacobi fields orthogonal to the geodesic are linearly independent at any point along the geodesic, then they are linearly independent on the entire geodesic.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Let $\Omega(S,x)$ denote the set of curves from $S$ to $x$. Suppose $\gamma$ is a length minimizing geodesic in $\Omega(S,x)$. Then the second variation formula for the _energy_ is $$ H_\gamma(V,W) = \int \langle V', W'\rangle - R(V,\gamma', W,\gamma') \mathrm{d}\tau - \langle \gamma'(0), II(V_0, W_0)\rangle $$ So the proof that minimizing geodesics cannot go past a conjugate point goes through pretty much line by line. (1) Suppose $\gamma$ as a focal point before $x$. Let $V$ be such that before the focal point it is a non-trivial Jacobi field vanishing at $x$...

Comment: ... and after the focal point it is identically 0. Choose $W$ to be an arbitrary vector field along $\gamma$ such that $W(0) =0$ and $\langle W, V'\rangle$ is non-zero at the focal point. Here we interpret $V'$ as the derivative from below the focal point. Then we have that $H_\gamma( V + \epsilon W, V + \epsilon W) < 0$ for some sufficiently small $\epsilon$ of the appropriate sign.

Comment: @DeaneYang After some thought, I actually do not see why you can choose $\Omega$ to be *open*. If $exp:\Omega \to M$ is a bijection, the natural candidate I see for $\Omega$ is $\Omega=\{(s,v)\in NS|\, \,  exp_s(tv) \,  \text{ is the unique minimizing geodesic from } s \in S \text{ to } exp_s(v)  \}$ which is not trivially open. Actually, I think it is always closed. If $\Omega$ is also open, this forces (assuming connectedness of $S$) $\Omega=NS$, which is indeed the picture I have in mind when imagining my original example where $M$ is unbounded.

Comment: However, I do not see a general argument for openness, but perhaps I am missing something obvious. (you can see further details in the beginning of my answer)...

Comment: The openness of the exponential map requires the generalization of the fact that a geodesic emanating from $S$ is never minimizing past a focal point, if any, on the geodesic. The proof is analogous to the proof a similar statement for a conjugate point. See the last two comments above by Willie Wong. On the other hand, by the definition of a focal point, the exponential map fails to be a diffeomorphism at $(x,v) \in \Omega$ if and only if $\mathrm{exp}(x,v)$ is a focal point.

Answer (score 2):

When $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S$ is at least $C^2$, your map $\tilde{s}$ is $C^1$ except at points $p$ where $d_S(p)={1\over\kappa(\tilde{s}(p))}$, where $\kappa$ is the largest principal curvature of $S$ at $\tilde{s}(p)$. The proof boils down to the inverse function theorem, and <s>I don't think is much harder in the general Riemannian case</s> (After giving it some thought, it seems that the proof in the Euclidean case does not apply readily to the Riemannian case).

Most references are concerned with the smoothness of the distance function $d_S$, but the smoothness of $\tilde{s}$ comes as a byproduct and is usually buried in the proof. See for example http://www.ams.org/tran/2007-359-12/S0002-9947-07-04260-2/

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate on why $\tilde s$ is not differentiable at the points you mentioned?

Comment: @AsafShachar: I think it is meant that $\tilde{s}$ is $C^1$ except _possibly_ at points $p$ where ... There are obviously points that satisfy the condition $d_s(p) = 1 / \kappa(\tilde{s}(p))$ where $\tilde{s}$ is still $C^1$; for example, points on the convex side of the surface $S$.

Comment: OK, is it easy to see then why in all the other points $\tilde s$ is indeed differentiable?

Comment: A high powered way to do this is to use what Deane [wrote](http://mathoverflow.net/a/242044/3948) + my comment thereof. Roughly speaking the condition $d_S(p) = 1/\kappa$ is implied by "being a focal point". An alternative way to see what was written here is to note that the normal exponential map on $S$ is a diffeomorphism to its image when restricted to $U$ in the normal bundle of $S$ where for $s\in S$ we have the section $U_s \subset B(s; 1 / \kappa)$ where $\kappa$ is the largest principal curvature at $s$.

Comment: The final statement in the previous comment can be found in most textbooks on differential geometry of curves and surfaces, and boils down to some multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 1):

The following paper discusses precisely the relation of smoothness and closest point property:

http://persweb.wabash.edu/facstaff/footer/papers/regofdistfun.pdf

See also [Unexpected regularity of the distance from a $C^2$ submanifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239202/unexpected-regularity-of-the-distance-from-a-c2-submanifold?noredirect=1#comment592372_239202)

Comment: The first paper (presumably the second post also) discusses regularity of the distance function, whereas the original question here is about the regularity of the unique closest point in a sub-manifold, if the latter is defined.

Comment: The paper alzo discusses the regularity of the projection to the submanifold, which is, when defined, the unique closest point.

Comment: OK I guess the lemma is somewhat related. But the neighborhood U cannot be any that satisfies the unique closest point property.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\til}{\tilde}$

This is an attempt to prove rigorously that there exists an *open* subset $\Omega$ of the normal bundle to $S$, such that $exp:\Omega \to M$ is a bijection. This proof seems to work only when $S$ is compact.

Reminder-we assume the following:

1) For every point in $M$, there exist a unique closest point in $S$

2) For every point in $M$, there exist a unique minimizing geodesic from it to $S$

Define $\Omega=\{(s,v)\in NS|\, \,  exp_s(tv) \,  \text{ is the unique minimizing geodesic from } s \in S \text{ to } exp_s(v)  \}$

Assumption (2) (together with the fact minimizing geodesics are orthogonal to the submanifold) implies that $exp: \Omega \to M$ is a bijection. (This is the *only* candidate).

Assume by contradiction $\Omega$ is not open, then there exists a point $(s,v)$ in $\Omega$, and a sequence $(s_n,v_n)$ in $NS\setminus\Omega$ converging to $(s,v)$. By the definition of $\Omega$, there exists a sequnce $(\til s_n,\til v_n) \in NS$ s.t $exp_{\til s_n}\til v_n=exp_{s_n}v_n$, $|\til v_n| < |v_n|$ (the norms are taken w.r.t the metric at the different base points). since $S$ is compact, $NS$ is also compact, so we can assume $(\til s_n,\til v_n)$ is converging to some $(\til s,\til v) \in NS$. Then, continuity of $exp$ forces $exp_{\til s}\til v=exp_sv$, and continuity of the metric forces $|\til v| \le |v| $.

**The only thing we can conclude  is that $(s,v)=(\til s,\til v)$....**

**Actually I think $\Omega$ must be closed:** If $\Omega \ni (s_n,v_n) \to (s,v)$ then $exp_{s_n}v_n \to exp_sv$. It is not hard to see that if there is a geodesic from $S$ to $exp_sv$ whose length is smaller than $|v|$, then the $v_n$ won't be the optimal lengths of geodesics from $S$ to $exp_{s_n}v_n$, for $n$ sufficiently large.

---

I am trying to fill in some details based on Deane's **original answer** (now changed) and Willie's comments, for the case when $M$ is an open Riemannian manifold and $S\subset M$ a submanifold such that there is a unique minimal geodesic joining each $x \in M$ to $\tilde{s}(x) \in S$.

**Given $v \in T_xM$**, Let $\alpha(\tau)$ be a path in $M$, $\alpha(0)=x,\dot \alpha(0) =v$. **Given $\alpha$** there exists a **unique** 1-parameter family of of constant speed minimal geodesics **along $\alpha$**, i.e:

$f: (t,\tau) \in [0,1] \times (-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow M$  such that:
$$f(0,0) = x, f(1,0) = \tilde{s}(x), \,f(t,0) \text{ is the unique minimizing geodesic from } x \text{ to } \tilde s(x),$$ $$ f(0,\tau)=\alpha(\tau), \, f(t,\tau) \text{ is the unique minimizing geodesic from  } \alpha(\tau) \text{ to }  \tilde s(\alpha(\tau))$$

Notice, that the associated Jacobi field is $J(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau} (t,0)$, and that $\tilde s(\alpha(\tau))=f(1,\tau)$, hence 
$$\frac{d}{d\tau}|_{s=0}\tilde s(\alpha(\tau))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau} (1,0)=J(1)$$

The Jacobi field $J(t)$ satisfies $J(0) = \dot \alpha(0)=v$. **We would like to show that $J(1)$ is in fact the directional derivative of $\tilde{s}$ in the direction $v$.** A-priori, $J$ might depend on the chosen path $\alpha$ which represents $v \in T_xM$. (Note that $J(1)$ depends on $f(1,\tau)=\tilde s(\alpha(\tau))$).

In order to do so we will show $\frac{DJ}{Dt}(0)$ is determined only by $v$. (Since a Jacobi field $J(t)$ is uniquely determined by $J(0),\frac{DJ}{Dt}(0)$ this finishes the proof of independence).

We can represent the family $f$ via the exponential map as follows: $$f(t,\tau)=exp_{\alpha(\tau)}\big(tv(\tau)\big) $$

$$\frac{DJ}{Dt}(t)=\frac{D}{Dt}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau} (t,0)=\frac{D}{D\tau}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (t,0)$$

Note that,
$$\frac{D}{D\tau}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (t,\tau)=\frac{D}{D\tau}d(exp_{\alpha(\tau)})_{tv(\tau)}(v(\tau)),$$

So

$$ \frac{DJ}{Dt}(0)= \frac{D}{D\tau}d(exp_{\alpha(\tau)})_0(v(\tau))|_{\tau=0}=\frac{D}{D\tau}(v(\tau))|_{\tau=0}=\frac{Dv}{D\tau}(0)$$

**Here I am stuck**. How can we show $\frac{Dv}{D\tau}(0)$ depends only on $v$ (and not on $\alpha$)?

**Other points that need clarification:**

1) Demonstrate linearity in $v$:

For a function to be differentiable, the directional derivatives needs to be linear in their arguments. Of course, since Jacobi equation is linear, and we know $J_v(0)=v$ (which is linear), then if we could show $\frac{DJ_v}{Dt}(0)$ depends linarly on $v$ we were done.

2) Finally, linear behaviour of the directional derivatives does not in general imply differentiability.

Comment: I'll take a look at your answer and might try to rewrite my answer with more details.

Comment: A few comments. First  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_field#Solving_the_Jacobi_equation may help. For the argument to work you probably need $v$ to be orthogonal to the minimizing geodesic to ensure $J(1)$ is parallel to $S$. (Think about the case where $\alpha$ is equal to the minimizing geodesic.)

Comment: The problem with $D_t J_v$ is real, however, because you have to choose it _so that the perturbed geodesic is the minimizing geodesic from the nearby point to $S$_. Deane mentioned Sturm-Liouville in his comments: a slight problem is that the endpoint "1" is not always "1"; you have a bit of a free boundary issue there due to what I wrote in my previous comment. These can all be sorted out using some sort of inverse function theorem argument. But if you are going that way you might as well just directly prove that for every $x\in M$ and $\tilde{s}(x)\in S$, that the normal exponential map..

Comment: from $S$, based at $\tilde{s}(x)$ with appropriate velocity, has surjective differential, and use the local inverse function theorem. Since now the "constrained" surface $S$ is on the side of the initial data,, and not the final data, you avoid the free boundary problem. And now at the initial data level you have the right degree of freedom: $v \in T_{\tilde{s}} S$ has  $\dim(S)$, and $J'(0)$ has $\dim(M) - \dim(S)$ after using the constraint that your Jacobi field corresponds to a family of geodesics orthogonal to $S$. (You can pick the components of $J'(0)$ orthogonal to $S$ freely, but...

Comment: ... the tangential components are determined by $J(0)$ (which is tangent) by the shape operator of $S$).